# dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 0: field name 'ELF' must be followed by colon; what can I do to solve this?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, wine

i tried running dpkg manually,then this error accrued 'dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 0:
field name 'ELF' must be followed by colon'; this is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `/var/lib/dpkg/status` should be pure text...

```
$ head -n 5 /var/lib/dpkg/status 
Package: accountsservice
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: adminsome
Installed-Size: 452
```

The word `ELF` makes me think your file is corrupted or replaced (with a executable binary file)...

```
$ od -Ax -t x1z -w16  `which head` | head -n 5
000000 7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >.ELF............<
000010 03 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00 10 37 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..>......7......<
000020 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f8 b1 00 00 00 00 00 00  >@...............<
000030 00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00 0d 00 40 00 1e 00 1d 00  >....@.8...@.....<
000040 06 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >........@.......<
```

*^^^- A hexdump of the head binary file, as expected it has ELF in the first few bytes.*

---

Try `$ file /var/lib/dpkg/status` it should say
`/var/lib/dpkg/status: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long line`
... not anything else...

An executable file:

```
$ file $(which head)
/usr/bin/head: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object,  ...
```